# Failed making directory in external storage in android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-external-storage

I have this method but why is it failing to create a directory in pictures folder?

```
    private void CreateDirectoryForPictures()
    {
        App._dir = new File(
            Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures), "CameraAppDemo");
        if (!App._dir.Exists())
        {
            App._dir.Mkdirs();
        }
        if (!App._dir.Exists())
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Directory not created", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Directory created", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the manifest?

Comment: oh sorry i forgot :D it's hard to know if what we are using are needing permissions when it is not stated in some tutorials :D

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Comment: @jace Also check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33162451/5134647 , for sdk 23 and above